# ContourPlot — How do I color by contour curvature?

Tags: plotting, color

I'm plotting the stream lines of fluid flow past a cylinder, and I would like the colors to increase with contour curvature (i.e. increase as the velocity of the flow increases. Here's a MWE that seems to color it based on the the y-axis value:

```
ψ[r_, θ_] := U (r - a^2/r) Sin[θ]
r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
θ = ArcSin[y/r];

stream = ContourPlot[
            ψ[r, θ] /. {U -> 10, a -> 1}, 
            {x, -5,5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
            Contours -> 10 Table[i, {i, -10, 10, 0.025}]
         ];

cyl = Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}, 1]];

Show[stream, cyl]
```

[image: stream lines around a cylinder]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
f = {ψ[r, θ]} /. {U -> 10, a -> 1};
gradf = D[f, {{x, y}, 1}];
Hessf = D[f, {{x, y}, 2}];
normal = gradf[[1]]/Sqrt[gradf[[1]].gradf[[1]]] // Simplify;
secondfundamentalform = -PseudoInverse[gradf].Hessf // ComplexExpand // Simplify;
tangent = RotationMatrix[Pi/2].normal;
curvaturevector = (secondfundamentalform.tangent).tangent // Simplify;
signedcurvature = curvaturevector.normal // Simplify;

stream = ContourPlot[
   ψ[r, θ] /. {U -> 10, a -> 1}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
   Contours -> 10 Table[i, {i, -10, 10, 0.2}],
   ContourShading -> None
   ];
curvatureplot = DensityPlot[signedcurvature, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
   ColorFunction -> "RedGreenSplit",
   ClippingStyle -> Automatic,
   PlotPoints -> 100,
   PlotRange -> {-1, 1}
   ];
Show[
 curvatureplot,
 stream,
 cyl
 ]
```

[image]